# How to inner join three tables with XMLTABLE in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, xmltable

I have a table called `XML_INFRASTRUCTURE` which has the following design:

```
COLUMN_NAME  | DATA_TYPE          | NULLABLE
-------------|--------------------|--------
XMLI_ID      | NUMBER(10,0)       | No
FILENAME     | VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) | Yes
LAST_VERSION | DATE               | Yes
XML_RAW      | CLOB               | Yes
```

In this table I am storing all the XML files I'm receiving through FTP as an XMLTYPE. I use XMLTABLE to get the information out and it all works well, until I start joining tables.

In the `XML_INFRASTRUCTURE` I have the following data:

```
XMLI_ID | FILENAME     | LAST_VERSION | XML_RAW
--------|--------------|--------------|--------------------------------
1       | ptcar        | 07-JAN-18    | <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><cern:ptcars creationDate="2018-03-16T19:35:54" xmlns:cern="http://www.website.com/Infrastructure" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.website.com/Infrastructure ../ns/infrastructure.xsd"><cern:ptcar id="1" validFromDate="1996-06-02" validToDate="2007-12-08" ....>
2       | ptrefColumn  | 07-JAN-18    | <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><cern:ptrefColumns creationDate="2018-03-20T11:33:21" xmlns:cern="http://www.website.com/Infrastructure" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.website.com/Infrastructure ../ns/infrastructure.xsd"><cern:ptrefColumn id="279" validFromDate="1998-04-01" validToDate="2001-06-11" ....> 
3       | ptref        | 07-JAN-18    | <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><cern:ptrefs creationDate="2018-03-20T11:33:05" xmlns:cern="http://www.website.com/Infrastructure"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.website.com//Infrastructure ../ns/infrastructure.xsd"><cern:ptref id="232" validFromDate="1998-04-01" validToDate="2001-06-11" ....>
```

And next I have the following requirements:

Given values: ptrefId and givenDate

```
select a.longNameFrench , a.longNameDutch
from   ptcar as a, 
       ptrefColumn as b,
       ptref as c
where c.id = ptrefId
and b.id = c.ptrefColumnId
and a.id = b.ptcarId
and a.validFromDate <= givenDate
and a.validToDate >= givenDate
and b.validFromDate <= givenDate
and b.validToDate >= givenDate
and c.validFromDate <= givenDate
and c.validToDate >= givenDate
```

So knowing this, I tried getting the XML out with XMLTABLE, but I have no idea how to get the join up and running. As you can see I tried chaining the XMLTABLE, but like this it's been running for over an hour now.

```
SELECT X.LongNameFrench, X.LongNameDutch
FROM XML_Infrastructure,
    XMLTABLE(
        '$d/*:ptcars/*:ptcar'
        PASSING XMLTYPE(XML_Infrastructure.XML_RAW) as "d"
        COLUMNS
            Id              VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    '@*:id',
            LongNameFrench  VARCHAR2(60)    PATH    '@*:longNameFrench',
            LongNameDutch   VARCHAR2(60)    PATH    '@*:longNameDutch',
            ValidFromDate   VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    '@*:validFromDate',
            ValidToDate     VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    '@*:validToDate'
    ) AS X,
    XMLTABLE(
        '$d/*:ptrefColumns/*:ptrefColumn'
        PASSING XMLTYPE(XML_Infrastructure.XML_RAW) as "d"
        COLUMNS
            Id              VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    '@*:id',
            ValidFromDate   VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    '@*:validFromDate',
            ValidToDate     VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    '@*:validToDate'
    ) AS Y,
    XMLTABLE(
        '$d/*:ptrefs/*:ptref'
        PASSING XMLTYPE(XML_Infrastructure.XML_RAW) as "d"
        COLUMNS
            Id              VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    '@*:id',
            ValidFromDate   VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    '@*:validFromDate',
            ValidToDate     VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    '@*:validToDate'
    ) AS Z
WHERE Z.Id = '512'
AND FILENAME = 'ptcar';
```

Suggestions are very welcome! (Sorry for the overload of information)

Comment: Your XML is incomplete which doesn't entirely help, and doesn't seem to match your results - the ID 512 you're looking for doesn't exist, so I guess you mean 232 here; but the `ptcar` file doesn't have the data form the other two XML documents. So, presumably, you need to combine the data from the XML from all three rows. So how are the three rows in the table related - purely by the `last_version` date?

Comment: @AlexPoole the relation between all xml files are noted in the requirements. `ptcar.Id = ptrefColumn.Id`, `ptrefColumn.Id = ptref.ptrefColumnId` and `c.id = ptrefId` (given variable)

Comment: Your three XML documents have different IDs though, and none of those are 512. Assuming those all refer to the same `id` node. So your examples should all have `id="512"`?

Comment: The 512 was actually just an example. The XML has roughly between 5000-15000 lines, so it was just to indicate that there is XML stored in XML_RAW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a select (or create views) like this:

```
CREATE VIEW ptcar AS
SELECT Id, LongNameFrench, LongNameDutch,
    TO_DATE(x.ValidFromDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as ValidFromDate,
    ...
FROM XML_Infrastructure,
    XMLTABLE(
        '$d/*:ptcars/*:ptcar'
        PASSING XMLTYPE(XML_Infrastructure.XML_RAW) as "d"
        COLUMNS
            Id              VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    '@*:id',
            LongNameFrench  VARCHAR2(60)    PATH    '@*:longNameFrench',
            LongNameDutch   VARCHAR2(60)    PATH    '@*:longNameDutch',
            ValidFromDate   VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    '@*:validFromDate',
            ValidToDate     VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    '@*:validToDate'
    ) as x;

CREATE VIEW ptrefColumn AS
SELECT Id,
    TO_DATE(x.ValidFromDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as ValidFromDate,
    ...
FROM XML_Infrastructure,
XMLTABLE(
    '$d/*:ptrefColumns/*:ptrefColumn'
    PASSING XMLTYPE(XML_Infrastructure.XML_RAW) as "d"
    COLUMNS
        Id              VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    '@*:id',
        ValidFromDate   VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    '@*:validFromDate',
        ValidToDate     VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    '@*:validToDate'
) as x
```

Afterwards you can join them directly as given in your question.

NB, why do you store `XML_RAW` as `CLOB` rather than `XMLTYPE`?

Comment: I had the same idea, but didn't know how to do it. Views could be a good solution. I'll try that out now. As for the datatype for XML_RAW, I honestly can't remember, but I'm guessing it has either to do with convenience or with the size of the XML's where a clob made easier to insert.

Comment: So after testing this, I managed to get all my data after 49.079 seconds, which is still quite a lot, knowing that you need to run 6 simular queries to load 1 page.

Comment: @JorisDecraecker, maybe you can create some indexes, have a look at [Indexes for XMLType Data](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb_indexing.htm#ADXDB0500)

Comment: I'll look into indexing into the next release. I made small compressing tool for XML files and managed to reduce the size of all the XML files by 80%. loading time is now 4.3s instead of 49.079s!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the three XMLTable results X, Y and Z from the same XML document, and that only has the `ptcar` node - so Y and Z don't find any data (as there are no nodes matching those XPaths).

Given the similarities between the three XML documents, and assuming the ID nodes you've shown are all supposed to be the same value (which isn't the case in your example data), you could use a single XMLTable to extract all of the relevant data from all of the documents:

```
SELECT X.Name, X.Id, X.ValidFromDate, X.ValidToDate, X.LongNameFrench, X.LongNameDutch
FROM XML_Infrastructure
CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
        '$d/*/*'
        PASSING XMLTYPE(XML_Infrastructure.XML_RAW) as "d"
        COLUMNS
            Name            VARCHAR2(10)    PATH    './local-name()',
            Id              NUMBER          PATH    '@*:id',
            LongNameFrench  VARCHAR2(60)    PATH    '@*:longNameFrench',
            LongNameDutch   VARCHAR2(60)    PATH    '@*:longNameDutch',
            ValidFromDate   DATE            PATH    '@*:validFromDate',
            ValidToDate     DATE            PATH    '@*:validToDate'
    ) X;
```

This uses wildcards to get any child node, but you coudl filter that if you have other types you haven't shown. It also adds a `name` column so you can tell which document each row came from (or you could include the file name if you prefer). It will give null values for the attributes that don't exist in all three.

And then use that in a CTE and join that to itself twice:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT X.Name, X.Id, X.ValidFromDate, X.ValidToDate, X.LongNameFrench, X.LongNameDutch
  FROM XML_Infrastructure
  CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
          '$d/*/*'
          PASSING XMLTYPE(XML_Infrastructure.XML_RAW) as "d"
          COLUMNS
              Name            VARCHAR2(30)    PATH    './local-name()',
              Id              NUMBER          PATH    '@*:id',
              LongNameFrench  VARCHAR2(60)    PATH    '@*:longNameFrench',
              LongNameDutch   VARCHAR2(60)    PATH    '@*:longNameDutch',
              ValidFromDate   DATE            PATH    '@*:validFromDate',
              ValidToDate     DATE            PATH    '@*:validToDate'
      ) AS X
)
select a.longNameFrench, a.longNameDutch
from cte a
join cte b on b.id = a.id
join cte c on c.id = b.id
where c.name = 'ptref'
and b.name = 'ptrefColumn'
and a.name = 'ptcar'
and c.id = ptrefId
and a.validFromDate <= givenDate
and a.validToDate >= givenDate
and b.validFromDate <= givenDate
and b.validToDate >= givenDate
and c.validFromDate <= givenDate
and c.validToDate >= givenDate;
```

This is somewhat similar to creating views of the queries for each document type and then joining those, but without needing any new permanent objects.

With your partial sample data in another CTE, and setting all the IDs to 512 and adding the missing names in `ptcar`:

```
with XML_INFRASTRUCTURE (XMLI_ID, FILENAME, LAST_VERSION, XML_RAW) as (
  select cast (1 as number(2,0)), cast('ptcar' as varchar2(255)), date '2018-01-07', to_clob('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<cern:ptcars creationDate="2018-03-16T19:35:54" xmlns:cern="http://www.website.com/Infrastructure" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.website.com/Infrastructure ../ns/infrastructure.xsd">
 <cern:ptcar id="512" validFromDate="1996-06-02" validToDate="2007-12-08" longNameFrench="Jean Dupont" longNameDutch="Jan Jansen"/>
</cern:ptcars>') from dual
  union all select 2, 'ptrefColumn', date '2018-01-07', to_clob('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<cern:ptrefColumns creationDate="2018-03-20T11:33:21" xmlns:cern="http://www.website.com/Infrastructure" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.website.com/Infrastructure ../ns/infrastructure.xsd">
 <cern:ptrefColumn id="512" validFromDate="1998-04-01" validToDate="2001-06-11" />
</cern:ptrefColumns>') from dual
  union all select 3, 'ptref', date '2018-01-07', to_clob('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<cern:ptrefs creationDate="2018-03-20T11:33:05" xmlns:cern="http://www.website.com/Infrastructure" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.website.com//Infrastructure ../ns/infrastructure.xsd">
 <cern:ptref id="512" validFromDate="1998-04-01" validToDate="2001-06-11" />
</cern:ptrefs>') from dual
),
cte AS (
  SELECT X.Name, X.Id, X.ValidFromDate, X.ValidToDate, X.LongNameFrench, X.LongNameDutch
  FROM XML_Infrastructure
  CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
          '$d/*/*'
          PASSING XMLTYPE(XML_Infrastructure.XML_RAW) as "d"
          COLUMNS
              Name            VARCHAR2(30)    PATH    './local-name()',
              Id              NUMBER          PATH    '@*:id',
              LongNameFrench  VARCHAR2(60)    PATH    '@*:longNameFrench',
              LongNameDutch   VARCHAR2(60)    PATH    '@*:longNameDutch',
              ValidFromDate   DATE            PATH    '@*:validFromDate',
              ValidToDate     DATE            PATH    '@*:validToDate'
      ) AS X
)
select a.longNameFrench, a.longNameDutch
from cte a
join cte b on b.id = a.id
join cte c on c.id = b.id
where c.name = 'ptref'
and b.name = 'ptrefColumn'
and a.name = 'ptcar'
and c.id = 512
and a.validFromDate <= date '2001-01-01'
and a.validToDate >= date '2001-01-01'
and b.validFromDate <= date '2001-01-01'
and b.validToDate >= date '2001-01-01'
and c.validFromDate <= date '2001-01-01'
and c.validToDate >= date '2001-01-01';
```

gives

```
LONGNAMEFRENCH                                               LONGNAMEDUTCH                                               
------------------------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------
Jean Dupont                                                  Jan Jansen
```

Comment: It's a working solution and I had no idea about the `/local-name()`, which is really useful. The issue with this solution is that since I'm working with huge amounts of XML data, I only received my data after 193.783 seconds, which might be a bit too long. This is even after I made it as specific as possible.